# Custom brushed not imported as a single image

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution, brushes

I'm importing a custom Alpha brush, although I have selected it as a single image, the brush looks like this:

[image]
[image]

I am trying to make dents into the mesh which is using a multiresolution modifier.

[image]